# App store connect operation error while distributing build to app store connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

[image]

I'm trying to upload flutter app build to app store connect but getting this error, any solution?

Comment: Did you try with `Transporter` App instead of direct Upload from `xcode`

Comment: Can you manually connect to iTunes Connect with safari ?

Comment: @RamprasathSelvam No I never used Transporter before but I'll give it a try for sure

Comment: @PtitXav When I tried to log in on iTunes connect in safari a popup came saying: Your **"Apple ID isn't enabled for iTunes Connect"**

Comment: Are you enrolled in Apple developer program ? Or are you in the authorised user for another developer account ?